# Python Vigenère cipher output doesn't match correct answer

Tags: python, vigenere

I wrote some code for decoding Vigenère cipher. But it always outputs a wrong decoded message.

And here's my code:

```
alphabet =  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p",        "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

v_message= "txm srom vkda gl lzlgzr qpdb? fepb ejac! ubr imn tapludwy mhfbz cza ruxzal wg zztylktoikqq!"

keyword = "friends"

def vigenere_cipher(message, keyword):
  decoded = []
  for i in range(len(message)):
    char = message[i]
    if char.isalpha():
      char_index = alphabet.index(char)
      key_index = alphabet.index(keyword[i % len(keyword)])
      letter_index = (char_index - key_index) % len(alphabet)
      decoded.append(alphabet[letter_index])
    else:
      decoded.append(char)
  return "".join(decoded)

print(vigenere_cipher(v_message, keyword))
```

The output it gave me is:

```
oge fowh ngqx bu hmioua mcaj? xacy zssy! cwa ezk ojhhhaet edsyh lrw ocsish to irplisoxagdn!
```

And I don't know what's wrong with it. Can anyone help and fix me my code please?

I have asked chatGPT as well but it cannot find the actual error.

Comment: OK, you think the output is wrong, but what would be the correct output? I mean: if you know it's wrong, please provide the output you wish for. That way if someone corrects your code, they can easily tell that the code works correctly (and so can you!). Please *edit* the question to add the correct output you expect. Then we can, for example, ensure that your idea of correct output is the same as our idea of the same.

Comment: One possible error is that `i` increments for spaces as well, so the offset in the key breaks quickly. That said, the [tool here](https://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher) decrypts the first three characters (before space) the same way. It also can crack it automatically, and according to it, the correct key is `VJSWNXI`, not `FRIENDS`.

Comment: Where does that ciphertext (txm srom vkda...) come from?

Comment: The [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher) description indicates shifting up to encrypt and down to decrypt, but this code does the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

1. You're shifting letters backwards in the alphabet, when you should shift them forwards. This is the opposite of the Vigenere cipher, as pointed out in the comments. So replace `letter_index = (char_index - key_index) % len(alphabet)` with `letter_index = (char_index + key_index) % len(alphabet)`
2. `i` should not be incremented for spaces.

```
def vigenere_cipher(message, keyword):
    decoded = []
    i = 0
    for char in message:
        if char.isalpha():
            char_index = alphabet.index(char)
            key_index = alphabet.index(keyword[i % len(keyword)])
            letter_index = (char_index + key_index) % len(alphabet)
            decoded.append(alphabet[letter_index])
            i += 1
        else:
            decoded.append(char)
    return "".join(decoded)
```

This will print:

> you were able to decode this? nice work! you are becoming quite the expert at cryptography!

Comment: But shifting forward is applied on encryption, on decryption it's backwards. That means that the original cypher is not the classical Vigenere.

Comment: Are you sure that you're correctly implementing the Vigenère cipher? There are numerous online solvers and none (that I've tried) will produce that output for the given encoded string and key

Comment: @CtrlZ Not exactly. As noted by bereal, this implementation shifts the letters in the opposite direction of the classic Vigenere cipher. It does answer the question posed by OP, though, with the given message and keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between Vigenère encoding and decoding is one piece of arithmetic. Thus both activities can be carried out in a single function that gets passed a Callable that will handle this variation.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import cycle
from operator import add, sub
from collections.abc import Callable

AMAP = {c: o for o, c in enumerate(ascii_lowercase)}


def crypto(msg: str, key: str, func: Callable) -> str:
    assert msg.lower() == msg and key.lower() == key
    rv = ""
    k = cycle(key)
    for c in msg:
        if c in AMAP:
            a = AMAP[c]
            b = AMAP[next(k)]
            p = func(a, b)
            rv += ascii_lowercase[p % 26]
        else:
            rv += c
    return rv


def encrypt(msg: str, key: str) -> str:
    return crypto(msg, key, add)


def decrypt(msg: str, key: str) -> str:
    return crypto(msg, key, sub)


KEY = "friends"
msg = "you were able to decode this? nice work! you are becoming quite the expert at cryptography!"

enc = encrypt(msg, KEY)
print(enc)
print(decrypt(enc, KEY))
```

**Output:**

```
dfc aruw fsti gr vjtwhr wznj? vmph otis! cbx swv jipreneo uhllj kpi rahjib eg fjdgbstusuyg!
you were able to decode this? nice work! you are becoming quite the expert at cryptography!
```

**Note:**

```
This code only works for lowercase ASCII
```